# Try to Fix 301 Redirect of a Dynamic URL | Not Working

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to 301 redirect the URL `/topics/blog/dot-net/?page_id=386` to `http://www.example.com/dot-net`.

I have tried like below:

```
Redirect 301 /topics/blog/dot-net/?page_id=386 http://www.example.com/dot-net
```

Above will not work i was sure but just tried.

And this one:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /topics/blog/dot-net/?page_id=386(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /dot-net? [R=301,L]
```

If you know something about this issue. How i could fix this in .htaccess please give me a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

A mod_alias `Redirect` cannot be used to match against the query string. Your mod_rewrite attempt potentially should work. There might be a caching issue (from previous failed attempts). However, if you just want to redirect the stated URL then it can be written something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page_id=396$
RewriteRule ^topics/blog/dot-net/$ /dot-net? [R=302,L]
```

It is more efficient to check the URL-path in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*, rather than use a generic *catch-all*.

You would only need to check against `THE_REQUEST` if you needed to prevent a rewrite loop - but this is not stated in your question.

Change the `302` (temporary) to `301` (permanent) when you are sure it's working OK.

Comment: Did not worked. I have used the code like below, I have put the code under the previous one in my HTACCESS. Do i have to put the code anywhere else.

`# Begin 301
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page_id=386$
RewriteRule ^topics/blog/dot-net/$ /dot-net? [R=302,L]`

Comment: "Did not work" - in what way did it not work? Did it not do anything? The order of directives in .htaccess is important. If you have other directives then the above redirect should go after any canonical redirects, but before any other rewrites. The code in your comment looks OK. You should include your complete .htaccess file in your question so we can debug this further. Presumably the canonical `example.com` to `www.example.com` redirect is working OK?

Comment: I've had a quick look at the `.htaccess` file you linked to (comment since deleted?). To be honest, it is a bit of a "mash" unfortunately (it looks like 101 different WordPress plugins have "had a go"?!). However, if you were to put the above directives at the _very top_ of the .htaccess file, it "should" perform the redirect as stated. But... the "very top" is probably not the _correct_ place for these directives. Any canonical redirects and access control (performed through mod_rewrite) should come first.